# Reverse polarity protection on AD623 inputs used to measure low voltages on a sense resistor

Tags: current-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier, reverse-polarity

This circuit used to measure low voltages on a sense resistor is part of my current meter in arduino that measures currents from 0.005ma to 5A.

[image]

I configure the gain of the instrumentation amplifier with a value of 100.

On the sense resistor the min voltage on its terminals is 0.00005v and max voltage 0.05v.

Actually I have the circuit working ok but I need is a way of reverse polarity protection on the inputs of AD623 to protect for example if I connect the wrong way the inputs to measure current on a Li-Po battery.

Is there a way to get that protection and keep the accuracy of the circuit?

Comment: Why are you concerned about a reverse polarity on the inputs? What harm do you expect will occur?

Comment: @brhans I would like to know if the inputs will damage on a reverse polarity situacion when the instrumentation amplifier attempts to amplify that voltage.

Comment: You have 0.05V on 5A? Make this a mechanical protection. The + and - connectors must be different, so they can not be mixed.

Comment: @marcosbc are you expecting the circuit to remain functional when reverse connected or, is that a problem that is self-revealing and you then fix it? I'm asking because this appears to be the only thing in your question that might be causing downvotes on my answer. My answer assumes that it's OK for the circuit to be non-operational when the current is reversed providing that the circuit isn't compromised such that it becomes broken or fails to work when current is correctly applied. Might this be the reason for two downvotes on my answer?

Comment: @Andyaka I recently saw your answer but I was not the one who downvote your answer. What I want with that protection is that the instrumentation amplifier inputs not get damaged in case were polarity inverted and so the circuit keep operational after that too.

Comment: @marcosbc no, I knew it wasn't you because you were not on this site during the period when the down votes appeared. So, just to be sure: you are not expecting the circuit to be functional when the current is in the wrong direction but, you do expect to the circuit to be functional when this reverse problem is fixed, yes?

Comment: @Andyaka yes thats what I need with this protection.

Comment: As long as the voltage on each input stays within the operating range specified in the datasheet, no protection is required. Swapping the polarity of the inputs will do no harm whatsoever to the in-amp. If you gave it a negative supply instead of ground you would see the output go negative - that's all.

Answer (score 2):

The data sheet advises this: -

[image]

So personally I'd use resistors in series with each input just to be 100% certain that even unreasonable voltage levels on the shunt resistor are catered for.

Comment: I get a bit confused about how to calculate Rlim based on page 17 of the datasheet (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad623.pdf). In my limit scenario 5A max, voltage over Rsense would be 0.05v and Vs = 5V. How can I calculate Vover on the inputs in that case?

Comment: If the Rlim resistors are (say) 220 ohm and the maximum allowed current into the op-amp pins are 10 mA (as stated in the data sheet) then, with resistors fitted, you add an extra 2.2 volt protection either side of the stated +/- limits.

Comment: thanks so much. With that resistor value I consider ok the protection having in mind that my max voltage input would be 0.05v.